# ZAP: Execute Script

Tags: scripting, zap

I try to execute the community script "Extender/HTTP Message Logger.js". I first double click on the script to make it open in the scripting console. However, in the scripting console, the "Execute" button is disabled and I see no other way how to make it run.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual issue was that I didn't read the script's code carefully: be default the script only logs JSON messages as defined on lines 17 and 43 and following. In order to log all the sent and received HTTP messages, I simply changed the `isMessageToLog(log)` function to always return true. After redeploying the script (disabling and enabling) it would log all HTTP messages.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing the message beneath the script which says:

> Extender scripts add new functionality, including graphical elements
>   and new API end points.
>
> Enabling a script installs it and disabling a script uninstalls it.

So you just need to enable the script (by right clicking it and selecting 'Enable') and then it will start working.

Comment: Indeed, I missed that information. However, I still have problems running this script. I am enabling the script, performing various tasks like spidering an URL or re-sending HTTP requests but the log file never shows up on my file system. I also changed the log file directory to be within $HOME,

Comment: Strange. Any errors in the zap.log file? https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/wiki/FAQhelp#check-the-log-file

Comment: Not at all. I was experiencing a "Data cache size limit is reached: 10000", which I guess is unrelated (plus I fixed it by changing the /Applications/OWASP ZAP.app/Contents/Java/zapdb.script entry SET FILES CACHE SIZE 40000). I am on Mac 10.13.14.